# How can i add a class with 'html' tag(not with body) for specified pages (10 nodeID's)?

Tags: hooks

How can i add a class with 'html' tag(not with body) for some specified pages (10 nodeID's) ? I tried with html preprocess, but didn't worked,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [`template_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/10.0.x) to your module and add the classes via `$variables['html_attributes']['class']`.

Since this is `html.html.twig`'s preprocessor, it has no notion of what a Node is. It could also be rendering a non-node page (e.g. the user login). Some modules may add Node information to the variables, but there is no guarantee. To be safe, you'll have to [check if the current route is a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/193029) and then check the IDs afterward.

```
function your_module_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ($is_current_rout_is_a_node) {
    if ($is_this_the_right_node) {
      $variables['html_attributes']['class'][] = 'your class';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/9.4.x/search/html.html.twig) in your theme as html--node--[NID].html.twig, and add the class into the HTML in that template.

```
<html{{ html_attributes.addAttribute("my attribute") }}>
```